# Use a KeyDown inside a Timer_Tick Event

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms, timer

Me and my buddy have been working on this magnifier application and we cannot make it work the way we want it.

The way we would like it to work:

1. Open app.
2. Move mouse to area you want magnified.
3. Hit enter.
4. Magnifying window moves to (offset) location of mouse and keeps updating that window for that specific location.
5. Hit enter again to move window to new cursor location.

Right now once i hit enter, the window follows the mouse because it goes into a for loop where it grabs "Cursor.Position". I've tried to save the Cursor.Position value at the "OnkeyDown" event and use it inside the timer loop but that won't work since it "does not exist in current context".

Can anyone see how i can do this?

Thanks in advance!

/Morten

```
/* O-button zooms out
 * I-button zooms in
 * Esc-button exits app
 * Enter moves magnifying window to new location (doesn't work)
*/
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Magnifier
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        Bitmap printscreen = new Bitmap(Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width, Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height);
        PictureBox pictureBox1 = new PictureBox();
        int zoom = 3; //zoom level
        public bool NewZoomLocation = false;
        public Form1()
        {


                {
                    InitializeComponent();
                    pictureBox1.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
                    pictureBox1.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle;
                    Controls.Add(pictureBox1);
                    FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;

                    Timer timer = new Timer();
                    timer.Interval = 100;
                    timer.Tick += timer_Tick;
                    timer.Start();
                }
           void timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {     var position = Cursor.Position;
              int xlocation = position.X;
              int ylocation = position.Y;
                {
                    try
                    {
                        var graphics = Graphics.FromImage(printscreen as Image);
                        graphics.CopyFromScreen(0, 0, 0, 0, printscreen.Size);
                        GC.Collect(); // Force the garbage collector (deals with memory leak)

                        if (NewZoomLocation == true)
                        {
                            var lensbmp = new Bitmap(50, 50); //Bitmap for Zoom window
                            var i = 0;
                            var j = 0;
                            for (int row = xlocation - 25; row < xlocation + 25; row++)
                            {
                                j = 0;
                                for (int column = ylocation - 25; column < ylocation + 25; column++)
                                {
                                    lensbmp.SetPixel(i, j, printscreen.GetPixel(row, column));

                                    j++;
                                }
                                i++;
                            }
                            this.pictureBox1.Image = new Bitmap(lensbmp, lensbmp.Width * zoom, lensbmp.Height * zoom);
                            Size = pictureBox1.Image.Size;
                            Left = xlocation - 45 * (zoom); //Horisontal position of final zoom window
                            Top = ylocation + 30; //Vertical position of final zoom window
                            TopMost = true;
                        }
                    }
                    catch //(Exception ex)
                    {
                        //MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                    }
                }
           }
        }

        protected override void OnKeyDown(KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.KeyValue == 73) // I-button to zoom in
                zoom++;
            else if (e.KeyValue == 79) // O-button to zoom in
                zoom--;
            else if (e.KeyValue == 27) // Esc-button to exit
            {
                Close();
                Dispose();
            }
            else if (e.KeyValue == 13) // Enter-button to choose zoon area
            {
                NewZoomLocation = true;
            }
            base.OnKeyDown(e);

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: So, you don't want the magnifier to follow the cursor? Well, your `NewZoomLocation` variable is always true _once it's set to true the first time_. You need to set it to false after re-locating your "window". Something like this: `if (NewZoomLocation == true) { DoYourWork(); NewZoomLocation = false; }`.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not really sure what you want to achieve here, however this should get you in a better place.

First thing first. The use of `GC.Collect` its because you are trying to plug a memory leak, if you ever create an image, dispose of it.

**Given some globals**

```
private readonly PictureBox pictureBox1 = new PictureBox();

private Bitmap _lastBmp = new Bitmap(300, 300);

private Point _position;

public bool NewZoomLocation;

private int zoom = 3; //zoom level
```

**Constructor**

```
public Form1()
{
   InitializeComponent();
   pictureBox1.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
   pictureBox1.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle;
   Controls.Add(pictureBox1);
   FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
   KeyPreview = true;
   Size = _lastBmp.Size;
   TopMost = true;
   var timer = new Timer();
   timer.Interval = 100;
   timer.Tick += timer_Tick;
   timer.Start();
}
```

**Cleanup**

```
protected override void OnClosed(EventArgs e)
{
   base.OnClosed(e);

   _lastBmp.Dispose();
   _lastBmp = null;
}
```

**Keydown**

```
protected override void OnPreviewKeyDown(PreviewKeyDownEventArgs e)
{
   base.OnPreviewKeyDown(e);
   switch (e.KeyCode)
   {
      case Keys.Enter:
         NewZoomLocation = true;
         _position = Cursor.Position;

         break;
      case Keys.Up:
         zoom++;
         break;
      case Keys.Down:
         zoom--;
         break;
      case Keys.Escape:
         Close();
         break;
   }
}
```

**Timer**

```
private void timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   if (NewZoomLocation)
   {
      var w = _lastBmp.Size.Width / zoom;
      var h = _lastBmp.Size.Height / zoom;
      var x = _position.X - w / 2;
      var y = _position.Y - h / 2;
      var size = new Size(w, h);    
      using (var screen = new Bitmap(size.Width, size.Height))
      {
         using (var g = Graphics.FromImage(screen))
         {
            g.CopyFromScreen(new Point(x, y), Point.Empty, size);
         }
         // resize
         using (var g = Graphics.FromImage(_lastBmp))
         {
            g.DrawImage(screen, new Rectangle(new Point(), _lastBmp.Size), new Rectangle(0, 0, w, h), GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
         }
      }

      pictureBox1.Image = _lastBmp;
   }
}
```

There is a lot more that can be done with this, however it should get you started. There is no memory leak anymore, it only grabs a screen shot of what it needs so will be faster.

Good luck